# ¿Como convertir imagen de Resources a Bitmap en Xamarin?

Tags: android, c#, imagen, xamarin, bitmap

Estoy desarrollando una App en la que genero un PDF, en dicho PDF tengo que poner el logo de la empresa que tengo guardado en la carpeta Resources/Drawable.
No consigo la forma de convertir dicho archivo en Bitmap para poder insertarlo en el PDF.

Por ahora tengo el siguiente código que aparentemente compila, pero al ejecutarlo da el siguiente error:

> System.InvalidCastException:

Que sale cuando quiere ejecutar la primera línea del código:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) Resource.Drawable.LogoEmpresa;
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.Bitmap;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
    byte[] imageInByte = stream.ToArray();
    Image image = Image.GetInstance(imageInByte);
    document.Add(image);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizalo de esta forma, esta es la forma de obtener un `bitmap` a partir de un `Drawable`:

```
Bitmap drawable = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.LogoEmpresa);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Miguel, funcionó sin problemas! :D

Answer (score 0):

Si analizamos la documentación:

[Images in Xamarin.Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images)

sobre el titulo `Embedded Images` observaras que utiliza

```
var embeddedImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg", typeof(EmbeddedImages).GetTypeInfo().Assembly) };
```

podrias aplicar esto mismo para obtener la imagen del recurso

Obtener el `Bitmap` en base a la `Image` es directo, usarías:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(embeddedImage);
```

Comment: Pero eso es para Xamarin.Forms... yo estoy haciendolo en Xamarin.Android